# Prove that in ring $\mathbb{Z}, \forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z} $, $(a,b) = (d)$, where $ d = \mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Prove that in ring $\mathbb{Z}, \forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z} $,
>   $$(a,b) = (d),$$ where $ d = \mathrm{gcd} (a,b)$. Also, generalize this for all finite generated ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$.

I don't even know how to start. I am not sure if I got the definition of generated ideal. When I have $(a)$, what does that mean?

Comment: Your book should at some point tell you exactly what something like $(a,b)$ means. Read that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- $x\in(a,b)\iff$ integers $n,m$ exist with $na+mb=x$
- $x\in(d)\iff$ integer $k$ exists with $kd=x$